# User with only Read-Only Console permission?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I would like to know if it is possible to add a user with "read-only" access to the Artemis Web console.
Right now we are in a point that is important to check if my application's consumer is created and connected to queues, if he is the only one connected, etc. And the easier place I can think of seein this is through Artemis Console. What I want is to create a user that can only see this information, the messages in the queues, etc., but cannot create new queues, send messages, purge queues, etc.
Is that possible?

I have tried following [this tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_amq/7.2/html/using_amq_broker/users) to create a user and play around with the roles but for some reason I can't even connect to the console with my created user. I keep getting "Forbidden".

Thanks!

**Edit**
What I have tried:

I have updated `artemis-users.properties` to have the following users:

```
admin = ENC(1024:5C41928065C0AED5B88F8DD66937F86F59BCF9F6BAC9097CD12C6D66FE83DC3B:DC9FCEECBBCB4849F3AE9570D83C8ABFDB1E03B0318F7B4BA128B9A174C00049C817FB2F7613D4A332BA1D1FF14C70F1E0492EECE747A6C7881E358F44CDB02C)
amqviewer = 123abc
```

The `admin` user was created when I have set up the broker. The `amqviewer` is the user I'm trying to have read-only permissions.

On the `artemis-roles.properties` I have set the `amqviewer` to have the `viewer` role (at least thats what I think after seeing how it was for the `admin` user):

```
amq = admin
viewer = amqviewer
```

and on the `management.xml` I have set the following:

```
   <authorisation>
      <whitelist>
         <entry domain="hawtio"/>
      </whitelist>
      <default-access>
         <access method="list*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="get*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="is*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="set*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="*" roles="amq"/>
      </default-access>
      <role-access>
         <match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis">
            <access method="list*" roles="amq"/>
            <access method="get*" roles="amq"/>
            <access method="is*" roles="amq"/>
            <access method="set*" roles="amq"/>
            <access method="*" roles="amq"/>
         </match>
         <match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis">
            <access method="list*" roles="viewer"/>
            <access method="get*" roles="viewer"/>
         </match>
      </role-access>
   </authorisation>
```

The thing is, I can't even get past the login. When I try to login with the `amqviewer` user, I get `forbidden`.

Answer (score 1):

To allow only read access in the webconsole, the role needs to be set in the management.xml and in the artemis.profile.

To configure the role readonly, Update the management.xml and artemis.profile as below.

```
    <role-access>
  <match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis">
     <access method="list*" roles="readonly,amq"/>
     <access method="get*" roles="readonly,amq"/>
     <access method="is*" roles="readonly,amq"/>
     <access method="set*" roles="update,amq"/>
     <access method="*" roles="amq"/>
  </match>
</role-access>
```

in artemis.profile: `-Dhawtio.roles=amq,readonly`

Refer: https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html.

Edit (as i am not able to reply in comment):

Everything you have done so far is right. you just need to the role "readonly" in the artemis.profile for the hawtio role.

```
in artemis.profile: -Dhawtio.roles=amq,readonly
```

you can verify whether you added successfully by the broker startup log. it will display as below.

```
2019-05-06 10:45:24,655 INFO  [io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "admin,readonly" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
```

Comment: Jesu hi, thanks for the answer. Still not able to configure this. Can you see my edit above?

Comment: It is working for me per Jesu's kind reply. I do note however that I did not add another match element as you (Joao) did. Instead I did as Jesu and the documentation said to do: add the new role in the existing match element.
There is a minor bug in what Jesu wrote; he mentioned both "readonly" and "viewer" - you should pick one of those names (any name will do), and that is what will appear in the logs.

Comment: My readonly user is still able to perform actions like addUser after following these steps. Any other recommendations?